# Fitting image in a frame inside Blender model using python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to update the content of an image in a GLB model imported by a Python script.

My script is importing the model and can replace any image without any issue, but the problem is in fitting this image within the frame.

More details, we have a frame, and we need the new image to fill it in two modes

- to maximize the image **proportionally** to fill the entire space of the frame
- to minimize the image **proportionally** to be fitted inside the frame even if it doesn't fill the frame

The same way as Windows does when you add an image to a slide, for example, a prompt asks you to apply the image fitting of the two mentioned modes.

---

**My question is**: how can I apply that in Blender so that my function is expected to take the image_path (str) and fitting_mode (max/fit), you can see the `logo` image in the screenshot below

Note:
I tried with `node.projection = 'BOX'` Box or Flat but nothing is useful.

All comments are appreciated

[image: fitting image inside a frame in Blender]